# Why doesn't SVG background color change?

Tags: html, css, svg

I've an issue by using an base64-encoded SVG. I used the following SVG:

[Menu Icon from iconmonstr](http://iconmonstr.com/menu-2-icon/)

I passed this file through:
[SVG Optimiser](http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg_optimiser)
& [Base64 Encoder](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/base64/base64.php)

Finally I created an a-element with two classes

```
.ui-icon-btn {
    display: block;
    background-color: red; //just a randomly picked color
}
.ui-icon-menu {
    display: block;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml; base64, [...]');

}
```

When I open Chrome's DevTools, it tells me, that the color has been overwritten. How can I avoid this?

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53Zsr/)

Comment: Probably an issue regarding specificity.. can you provide an example with the SVG?

Comment: I added it to my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just place `.ui-icon-btn` after `.ui-icon-menu` in the CSS.

It was being overwritten as the stylesheet is read from top to bottom.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/dWkLg/)

```
.ui-icon-menu {
    display: block;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background: url("");
}
.ui-icon-btn {
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `background-image` to add the image as opposed to  just `background` thus, it then wouldn't be overwritten. [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2e2g8/)

Comment: I'll try keeping this in memory, thank you! I appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 3):

The `background:` line is a shorthand for setting `background-image`, `background-color`,  `background-position` etc. If you change it to `background-image:` instead, it won't overwrite the `background-color` style.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between `image/svg+xml;` and `base64`. That's not allowed as per spec. See this corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/53Zsr/2/

Apart from that, set only the `background-image` property, if you want to keep the color intact.